# Plugin magento/inventory-composer-installer could not be initialized

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.3

When running `composer install` for fresh checkout of a project. (repo contains `composer.lock` that is working elsewhere) get the following error:

```
Plugin initialization failed (Plugin magento/inventory-composer-installer could not be initialized, class not found: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin), uninstalling plugin
  - Removing magento/inventory-composer-installer (1.2.0)
    Install of magento/inventory-composer-installer failed

                                                                                                                                    
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                                                                        
  Plugin magento/inventory-composer-installer could not be initialized, class not found: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin
```

- this is using the same version of PHP where the lock file was generated
- this is using the same version of composer where the lock file was generated
- `magento/product-community-edition`: `2.4.3`
- I have tried with and without `--no-dev`
- I have tried clearing the composer cache

I can replicate this 100% by either:

- `rm -rf vendor; composer install`
- `rm -rf vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer; composer install`

When the class doesn't exist in vendor, *because the composer hasn't installed it yet* it just falls over.

Answer (score 4):

The only workaround I have for this at the moment is to run

```
composer install --no-plugins
```

Which runs
Then following it up with

```
composer install
```

(to hopefully trigger the plugins)

Turns out this was actually a symptom of: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34325

I had to regenerate the lockfile, after removing the audit plugin, as described here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34325#issuecomment-941937222

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you're running an **outdated PHP version**, check if the version is the same in your deployment systems and servers.

Another possibility is not having **unzip** installed.
You can fix it by running:

```
apt update && apt install unzip -y
```

[image: Magento 2 unzip required]